# Find the domain of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n! x^{2n}} {n^n (1+x^{2n})}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n! x^{2n}} {n^n (1+x^{2n})}$$

Let $a_n= n!x^{2n}$, then by ratio test we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \Big{|}\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}\Big{|} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \Big{|}(1-\frac{1} {1+n})^n \frac{x^2+x^{2n+2}} {1+x^{2n+2}}\Big{|}=\frac{1} {e}\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} \Big{|}\frac{x^2+x^{2n+2}} {1+x^{2n+2}}\Big{|}<1 $$

How do I treat the last part to get the domain of convergence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, you have $$0\le \dfrac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}} < 1$$

This means:

$$0 \le \sum_{n\ge 1} \dfrac{n!x^{2n}}{n^n(1+x^{2n})} < \sum_{n\ge 1} \dfrac{n!}{n^n}$$

Since it is bounded and increasing as $|x|$ increases, if the RHS converges, you have convergence over all reals.

By the ratio test:

$$\dfrac{\left(\tfrac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\right)}{\left(\tfrac{n!}{n^n}\right)} = \dfrac{(n+1)n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} = \left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^n = \left( 1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^n \to \dfrac{1}{e} < 1$$

This implies the series converges absolutely.

Comment: Nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Split in the cases $|x|<1$, $|x|=1$ and $|x|>1$. How does the last part behave in the different cases?

Comment: I think I made the wrong limit...I have made the correction in my solution. Now for $|x|<1$, we have for the last part $\frac {1}{e}⋅0=0<1$; for $x=±1$, the last part becomes $\frac {1}{e}⋅1<1$; and for $|x|>1$, it becomes $\frac {1}{e}⋅1<1$ again. So this means the domain of convergence is $\mathbb{R}$. Am I right?

Comment: @ZelongLi. I agree.